# Writing back to HTML after reading form input doesn't work (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I try to follow the simple example on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_lib_jquery.asp) to read a value from a form and write back to the HTML page using pure Javascript.

Please refer to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3c6fda4g/) for the code:

```
<body>
    <form action="index.javascript.html" onsubmit="omzetten()">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Omzetten naar decimaal stelsel:</legend>
            <p class="loginlabel">Getal</p>
            <input type="text" id="getal" class="loginfield" />
        </fieldset>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" id="omzetten" value="Omzetten" />
    </form>
    <p id="antwoord">[empty]</p>
</body>
```

And in file app_javascripts.js in subdirectory /js (referred to in the header):

```
function omzetten() {

     var getal = document.getElementById("getal");
    var bronstelsel = 2;
    var antwoord = 0;
    var j = 0;
    for (var i = getal.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        antwoord += getal.substr(i, 1) * Math.pow(bronstelsel, j);
        j++;
    }
    var antwoordText = document.getElementById("antwoord");
    antwoordText.innerHTML = antwoord;
}
```

Why does the result ("antwoord") not show in paragraph-element with id "antwoord"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems.

First, you need to change the input to `type="submit"` so that it will invoke the `onsubmit` handler for the form. Another option would be to put the function call in the button's `onclick` attribute. If you're not submitting the form to a server, you don't really need the inputs to be inside a `<form>`.

Second, you need to add `return false;` to the `onsubmit`, so that it won't actually submit the form.

Third, you gave the function the same name as the `id` of the submit button. The problem with this is that IDs are automatically turned into global variables, which replaces the global variable containing the function. In my code below I simply removed the ID, since it's not used for anything.

Fourth, to get the input from the text field, you need to get its `.value` property:

```
var getal = document.getElementById("getal").value;
```

And specifically for the fiddle, you need to select one of the "No wrap" options from the menu at the top left. Otherwise, all the Javascript is inside the `window.onload` function, and functions are not in the global scope used by inline Javascript in tags.

```js
function omzetten() {

  // inputRead:
  var getal = document.getElementById("getal").value;
  var bronstelsel = 2;
  var antwoord = 0;
  var j = 0;
  for (var i = getal.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    antwoord += getal.substr(i, 1) * Math.pow(bronstelsel, j);
    j++;
  }
  var antwoordText = document.getElementById("antwoord");
  antwoordText.innerHTML = antwoord;
}
```

```html
<form action="index.javascript.html" onsubmit="omzetten(); return false;">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Omzetten naar decimaal stelsel:</legend>
    <p class="loginlabel">Getal</p>
    <input type="text" id="getal" class="loginfield" />
  </fieldset>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Omzetten" />
</form>
<p id="antwoord">[empty]</p>
```

Comment: Works completely! Can you explain why I get an error if I add the line 'onload omzetten;  like in the W3Schools code-example? Error is 'onlad is not defined'. Anything to do with your fifth comment (which I do not actually understand)?

Comment: It should be `onload = omzetten`. That runs the function when the page is first loaded.

Comment: When you use the `onLoad` option in jsfiddle, all the code is inside `window.onload = function() { <code> }`. The scope of all function decalarations in that `<code>` is just the body of that function, but `onXXX` attributes can only access global variables and functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your button to a submit:

```
<input type="submit" id="omzetten" value="Omzetten" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var getal = document.getElementById("getal");
```

[returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) an Element. However you are treating the Element like a string.

Use

```
var getal = document.getElementById("getal").value;
```

to retrieve the value from the 'getal' Element.

Additionally your function never executes because your form never submits. You would need an input of type 'submit'.

Updating the page after submitting a form may not be what you want. You might want to use onclick on your button rather than submitting the form.

Here is an [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3c6fda4g/16/). I changed from onsubmit to onclick (on the button), fixed the .value issue described above, and changed the function name because it conflicted with the button ID.